# How to extend a function defined on a continuum X to a function in the hyperspace defined by all non empty closed sets of X

Tags: general-topology

I'm having some trouble finding the "natural" extension of a retraction when I work on the hyperspace.

Maybe a little explanation on how hyperspaces work would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map between compact Hausdorff spaces (which is general enough for now), and $H(X)$ and $H(Y)$ are the hyperspaces of $X$ and $Y$ in the Vietoris topology (which coincides with the Hausdorff metric topology if a space is compact metrisable), then we can define a map $H(f)$ from $H(X) \rightarrow H(Y)$ by $H(f)(A) = f[A]$, just the image under $f$. If $A$ is non-empty closed (and maybe connected if working with the subspace of continua) then so is $f[A]$, using compactness to see $f$ is a closed map (and continuity to preserve connectedness). So $H(f)$ is well-defined.

One easily checks (nice exercise) that $H(f)$ is then also continuous. this is the natural map they mean, I think.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this helps, I actually thought about it but wasn't sure if I has the correct idea. I'll try to move from here. Thank you very much.

Comment: I hope you succeed